# How to count ForeignKey set where method returns True

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm creating a rating for contractors. A table on the page consists of the name, the amount of works he did, the rating which is calculated with (sum of ratings for works / the amount of works). I need to make queries to get the data. I have models:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # some fields in here

class Offer(models.Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    raiting = models.PositiveIntegerField() # 1-10

    def func(self):
        # returns boolean
```

Offer also has a func, which returns Boolean. As i said i need to count offers of each users which return True in func, a sum of raiting which return True in func and then render it all. I thought it should look like a json since we can't access some features of queries in a template, but still have no idea how to even design them

Comment: "of each users which return True in func" shouldn't it be a method of user then?

Comment: @KlausD. more like "of each user, which return True in method". Offers need to be validated by their own fields. Something like both customer and a contractor need to accept an Offer and that's when it returns true

Comment: I think we couldn't use model methods in queryset. you should put condition in queryset itself.